# Forward wifi thru p2p

Tags: wi-fi

sharing wifi internet via p2p
My android can connect to wifi at the same time it is operating p2p (wifi-direct) as a GO.
How can I go about sharing/forwarding internet connections (from wifi "wlan0") to the clients on my p2p group (interface "p2p0") ?
I have terrible wifi in the apartment, so I would like to set this Android up as a kind of makeshift repeater.

I feel like this is an iptables type of thing, but I am not sure.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: I am also looking for the exact same thing, and I found this project - https://github.com/shinilms/direct-net-share.

Have a look at the iptable commands in this file - https://github.com/shinilms/direct-net-share/blob/master/app/src/main/java/shinil/direct_share/RootManager.kt.

I wasn't able to get it working but it is a starting point.